# Infopath web browser forms

Tags: infopath

I have an infopath form published as Web Broswer enabled , this infopath form is a survey taken by many people in different teams (same person can work for 2 different teams) , I would like to restrict the person to take the survey only once based on the team he belongs. Please let me know how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3):

How about make every single feedback (infopath form) with a unique name with the person's name? So, he can't submit a 'duplicate' feedback.
For example, if Jony in both IT and Admin team, and Jony(IT) submitted his feedback with the infopath file name "Jony.xml". Then, Jony(Admin) can not submitted anymore, because "Jony.xml" already there.

Goto your infopath form library's settings page, make the name or title column unique.
Then, modify your infopath form's publish settings to provide a default file name with the current user's name and do not allow "Replace existing file".

Comment: Or, since it appears you want them to be able to submit for each team, but only once for each, make the name of the form a combination of their name and team so that she could submit for IT once and then Admin once.

Comment: i will try the suggestions provided.

Answer (score 1):

While submitting your Infopath form, save the form into the library with the submitted users Name and Department.

Here is an excellent post that describes how this can be done in simple steps using SharePoint builtin webservices- 
[http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/itaysk/archive/2007/04/05/InfoPath-*2D00*-Get-the-current-user-without-writing-code.aspx](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/itaysk/archive/2007/04/05/InfoPath-_2D00_-Get-the-current-user-without-writing-code.aspx)

Also, create a data connection that queries the results from the same SharePoint list and save it in some hidden fields.

On Submit button click, create a rule to compare whether the logged in user from the same department has previously submitted using the values in the hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

Is the form part of a library that you could probably restrict his access to?

Or does he need access to this lib but you want him to not access this form alone?

You could also setup Infopath forms security based on a group within your AD that has a set of users who are allowed to use it.

Comment: Sending the link to this form via email and all users have contribute access to Library. this infopath form is not in the Sharepoint web part; currently its published as Web Browser form.